# Как сделать правильный подбор чисел в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива - число `а`, которое может принадлежать числам 6,7,8,9 и сумма `а` и `b`, которая может принадлежать числам 11,12,13,14. 
Из массива `а` наугад выбирается одно из чисел. Далее я искал числа массива `b`, как разность `ab[j]-a[i]`

Т.к. `a+b` принадлежит числам 11,12,13,14, то соответственно в сумме не может быть чисел 10, 15 и т.д.

А у меня такие числа встречаются. Например, 6 и 2, 7 и 3, 9 и 8 и т.д.

Как исключить, например, для 6 цифры 2,3,4 для 7 цифры 2,3,8 и т.д  ???

Однако, цифры 2,3,4 нельзя совсем выкидывать из массива, т.к. например, 7+4=11 и т.д.

```js
var a  = [6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log( a );
console.log( " " );
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
console.log( a[rand] );
console.log( " " );

var ab = [11, 12, 13, 14];
var b = new Array( a.length * ab.length );
var c = new Array( a.length * ab.length );


for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {

  for (var j=0; j<ab.length; j++) {
    b[ i*a.length + j ] = ab[j]-a[i];
    var randB = Math.floor(Math.random() * b.length);
  }
}

console.log( " " );
console.log( b );
console.log( b[randB] );
```

Comment: там не ошибка, в массиве a+b вроде должно быть 12,13,14,15...

Comment: не, в массиве a+b должно быть 11,12,13,14

Comment: связан, мы же получаем из разности массива a+b(ab) и массива a массив b

Comment: да, уже понял, ошибся пока условие читал )

Comment: в одномерном массиве все `b` в любом случае не удастся хранить. Нельзя же их и хранить, и нет одновременно. Сделать двумерный массив `b` типа `[[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5]]`, если задача в том, чтобы получить все возможные числа b в виде массива.

Comment: Была мысль сделать в b двумерный массив. Только не могу допереть как. Моя задача, чтобы при сумме чисел a и b сумма не выходила за промежуток [11..14]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двумерный можно сделать, например, так. Если задача такая, может подойдет. Вообще это не двумерный, а ассоциативный массив получился. В качестве ключей - значения из массива `а`

```js
var a = [6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(a);
console.log(" ");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
console.log('a[rand] = ' + a[rand]);
console.log(" ");

var ab = [11, 12, 13, 14];
var b = {};

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b[a[i]] = new Array();
  for (var j = 0; j < ab.length; j++) {
    b[a[i]][j] = ab[j] - a[i];
  }
}

console.log('массив b для а = ' + a[rand] + ' : ' + b[a[rand]]);

// Случайное число из b:
rand_b = Math.floor(Math.random() * b[a[rand]].length);
console.log( 'Случайное число из b: '+ b[a[rand]][rand_b] );

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Есть один вопрос. Смотрите, вы b объявили, как объект. Есть массив b для а = 6 : 5,6,7,8. Как тут наугад вытащить или 5, или 6, или 7, или 8? Пробовал Math.floor(Math.random() * b.length) - естественно выводит NaN, ибо объект

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил вывод `b`

Comment: вытаскивать по идее так же, как и для `a`, только вместо него использовать нужный массив из `b` - `b[a[rand]]`

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!!!)

Comment: @Wexzuq Не за что, рад что удалось помочь =)